# Cells.Find and referencing another Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have two Workbooks. I need to take a String from WB1 (I iterate through Column C in WB1, not every cell contains a String, but when a cell contains a string this is the one I want to copy), find it in WB2 and replace it with another String from WB1 (in the same row, but column A). Here is what I have so far:

```
' Checks if a given File is already open
Public Function FileInUse(sFileName) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Open sFileName For Binary Access Read Lock Read As #1
    Close #1
    FileInUse = IIf(Err.Number > 0, True, False)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Sub copyPaste()

Dim destWB As Workbook
Dim destSH As Worksheet
Dim fileName As String
Dim curCell As Range
Dim oldName As Range
Dim result As Range

' turn off screen refresh, recalculate formula to speed up sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

' For i = 2 To Rows.Count
For i = 2 To 5
    fileName = "C:\Users...\" & Workbooks("Ressources calculation.xlsm").Worksheets("Tests costs").Cells(i, 2)

    If Not FileInUse(fileName) Then
        Set destWB = Workbooks.Open(fileName)
        Set destSH = destWB.Sheets("Qualification Matrix")
        destSH.Activate
    End If

    Set curCell = Workbooks("Ressources calculation.xlsm").Sheets("Tests costs").Cells(i, 3)
    Set oldName = Workbooks("Ressources calculation.xlsm").Sheets("Tests costs").Cells(i, 1)
    If Not IsEmpty(curCell) Then
        curCell.Copy
        Set result = destWB.Sheets("Qualification Matrix").Cells.Find(What:=oldName.Text, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True, MatchByte:=True)

        If Not result Is Nothing Then
            result.PasteSpecial
        End If
    End If
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

I have added a MsgBox in the "If Not result" clause which never triggers, so I guess it is not finding the cell. It seems to extract the strings I need to use (in curCell and oldName) fine though (checked also with MsgBox). The cells in which it should search and replace are merged cells, if that makes a difference. I also tried out different values for Cells.Find (leaving all optional parameters, tried all possibilities for lookIn and lookat, MatchByte, tried oldName.Value instead).

This is the first time I'm doing something with Excel Macros/VBA, the last few hours were spend with a lot of trial and error without any result. So I'm sure what I have so far is far from optimal, but I hope that someone can help me with it.

Edit: I narrowed it down a bit. I now activate destSH right before Cells.Find and tried just using a hardcoded example String as a parameter, which works. So I guess the problem is not the find statement but how I try to extract the information I'm looking for with find.

Edit2: As requested, here is a short example walkthrough:

I have a Workbook called "Ressources calculation.xlsm" with three Columns: Current name, File name, New name. Row 4 looks like this:

```
Misspelledd    [File name].xlsx    Misspelled
```

Not every Cell in Column C is filled out. What I'm trying to do is: Iterate through every cell in Column C, if it is not empty copy the string which is in the same row but in Column A, look for it in the file which is noted in Column B and replace it with the right name written under Column C.

Here is a picture of the cell in the destination Workbook which should be found and the text replaced as explained above. It is a merged cell, stretching over rows 2-5.
[image]

Edit 3: I finally found out what the problem was. There were "invisible" line breaks at the end of some cells (not really invisible, but you don't easily see them since there are no characters coming after). If this is not the case, the code works.

Comment: What happens when you use F8 instead of the message box? It's also strange that you are trying different combinations of arguments to `Find` instead of supplying the one that correctly describes your goal.

Comment: Don't know the content of your sheets, but you should use `oldName.Value`, not `oldName.Text`

Comment: I did try Find with what I think correctly describes my goal, but it did not work and I got feedback to try it with different arguments, so since I have no better plan I did. I have not thought about using F8 as I did not know this feature (well, not hard to find out about it, that's on me), thanks for that. I currently get `Object variable or with block variable not set` for my Cells.Find statement, which I do not remember getting a few days ago when I last worked on this...

Comment: @FunThomas that's good to know, thanks. I now found out that using a hardcoded string as a parameter for `Find` works, so the problem seems to lie somewhere in how I want to extract this information.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (added some debug.print for troubleshooting)

```
Sub copyPaste()

    Dim destWB As Workbook
    Dim destSH As Worksheet
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim curName, oldName
    Dim result As Range
    Dim wbRes As Workbook, wsTests As Worksheet

    Set wbRes = Workbooks("Ressources calculation.xlsm") 'ThisWorkbook ?
    Set wsTests = wbRes.Worksheets("Tests costs")

    For i = 2 To 5

        fileName = "C:\Users...\" & wsTests.Cells(i, 2)

        If Not FileInUse(fileName) Then
            Set destWB = Workbooks.Open(fileName)
            Set destSH = destWB.Sheets("Qualification Matrix")

            curName = Trim(wsTests.Cells(i, 3).Value) '<< always worth adding Trim()...
            oldName = Trim(wsTests.Cells(i, 1).Value)
            If Len(curName) > 0 Then
                Debug.Print "Looking for: '" & oldName & _
                      "' on sheet '" & destSH.Name & "' in " & _
                      destWB.FullName 

                Set result = destSH.UsedRange.Find(What:=oldName, _
                                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                                LookAt:=xlWhole)
                If Not result Is Nothing Then
                    Debug.Print "...found"
                    result.Value = curName
                Else
                    Debug.Print "... not found"
                End If
            End If
        End If      'file not in use

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried your code, and per the Debug.Print output it does extract the right name, but it does not find it in the destination Workbook. With my code I tried `Cells.Find` with a hardcoded string, and it worked. But as with your code, it does seem to extract the right name (I debugged with MsgBox) but does not find it  in the destination file. Actually I just tried your code with a hardcoded string in Cells.Find, and it worked like this as well.

Comment: I think we need to see exactly what it is you're searching for - can you update your post with some example search values, and maybe show a screenshot of one of the cells which should be found?  Something is not adding up here.

Comment: I edited my post, is this the information you are looking for?

Comment: If I update to `oldName = "Misspelledd"` and place the value to be found in a merged cell as you show, the Find() finds the match.  Still missing something.

Comment: Yes, before I tried it with placing the string directly in Find(), but it also works using this "way" of hardcoding, which should mean that the problem is in the line where you assign something to oldName? I'm not sure where else the mistake could be.

Comment: I found the problem. I failed to mention that some of the strings contain spaces between words - obviously that does not work when using Trim to cut out any spaces. Removing the trim statement works. I'm sorry, that is information I should have thought about supplying.

Comment: `Trim()` (in VBA) only removes spaces from the ends of a string, not from anywhere in the middle.

Comment: Oh - well, that is weird. Do you happen to have an idea why it works when I remove the trim and just do `oldName = wsTests.Cells(i, 1).Value` ?

Comment: If the cell to be found has leading or trailing spaces then Trim() would cause it to not be matched.

Comment: There are no leading or trailing spaces in the string I'm searching for. Also, and I have absolutely no idea why, it stopped working. And I can't get it to work again for the last few hours, even though I basically documented here what it took to get it to work the first time. I'm sure there is something very basic that I'm missing completely, otherwise I really can't explain how I'm so lost in this.

Comment: Are you able to share your workbook (or a stripped-down version which still shows the problem?)

Comment: I tried making a stripped down Version (I can't share the version with its content) by removing the content in every cell and writing random texts in some cells. And it works like this... I don't know why, and I guess sharing a stripped down version that does not show the problem isn't too useful, is it?

Comment: Is there *any* chance that when you run `Set destWB = Workbooks.Open(fileName)` the file is already open?  If that happens, you may end up with the wrong file referenced in `destWB`

Comment: Beefed up the Debug.Print above - might be worth running to double-check

Comment: The Debug.Print output is as it should be (apart from the not found). Looking for 'String that is definitely present (sheet is also right)' in 'Right file'  --> not found. I also just found out (when I tried to make another stripped down sheet) that it works when I copy the two files somewhere else, in this case they were in the same directory which originally, they are not (but the correct file is opened still and as I said, it works when I put the string directly, so I don't think I messed up on the path or so). I'll try it with another subdirectory.

Comment: It also works when I put the file that is to be edited in another subdirectory. I literally ctrl+c and ctrl+v those files, why would they work in another directory?

Comment: If the same exact file, it should not make any difference where they are.

Comment: Yes, that's what I would think, too. I deleted the files in the other directory, copied the originals over again (changed the path in the code) and it didn't work. Then I changed the sample text to search for and replace (also used two words seperated by a space) and it worked again. My testing generally seems to be really indeterministic. I'm not sure I can continue working on this right now, maybe I should sleep on it. Thanks a lot for helping me out so consistently, I'm sure this has been painful for you as well.

Comment: We all get stuck on "simple" problems!  If you have "spaces" between words it might be worth turning on word wrapping and checking that what looks like a space isn't (eg) a newline character or other type of white space.  Eg Asc160 "non-breaking space" which sometimes finds its way into Excel after a copy-paste from the web: that's not a space character but it behaves like one.

Comment: Unfortunately it does also not consistently work for single words :D I will still look into word wrapping tomorrow. Thanks a lot.